# What is the scope of the returned value in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics, memory-safety

What happens to the data referenced by the variable when it is returned to the caller? When the data is destroyed and possibly Drop trait gets executed?

Comment: Please post the code where you tried this and it didn't work. If you didn't try any code, why do you think it might not be possible?

Comment: My original description was not good at describing the problem. This really should not need any code example and I think it is a reasonable question (post-update).

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "scope"? I still believe that some code examples (even pseudocode) would help us understand what you want to know. As far as I can tell, the answer to your question is "it depends on what called it" (assuming that you mean *the return value of a function*).

Comment: For example when you have a struct that implements the Drop trait. If the value of that type is returned from a function, does drop() get called when leaving from that function or later?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can (why not?):

```
use std::io::File;

fn open_file(path: &Path) -> File {
  let file = File::open(path).unwrap() ;
  file
}


fn main() {
  let path = Path::new("hello.txt");
  let mut file = open_file(&path);

  let str =  file.read_to_string().unwrap();
  println!("Contents of {}:\n{}\n", path.display(), str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the life cycle of the data in Rust when I wrote this question. Returning a value causes ownership of the data to move to the variable assigned by the caller. Trivial but I just had started to experiment with the language when I wrote the question :)